# Basic inserts (for the application to work) in symfony2

Tags: symfony, configuration, doctrine

Is there a way in symfony2 that you can pre-define a procedure for inserting the basic data to the database for the application to work?, this is for not sharing an SQL script.

I see this as a doctrine procedure that is executed when you decide to update the schema. So it will check if there is the basic configuration data, if not, it will insert it. Is there something like that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

From the [Symfony2 website](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html)

You have to use DoctrineFixturesBundle

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a feature embedded in SF2 and / or Doctrine2.
But you can create your own command to add this behavior to your application / bundle :)

As Picoss said, there is the [Doctrine Fixtures Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) but it isn't part of the Symfony2 core.